# How to load data in a json file from table on starting the application?

Tags: javascript, json, database, servlets, struts

I have an json Object in .js File. I need to Load data in that object from a table at the start of the application. Object format is like this:-

```
               {'0':'Statement1',
                '1':'statement2',
                '2':'statement3',
                 .
                 .
                 . 
                 so on
                };
both index and statement column of that table need to populate data in this object at the start or load of the application. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Could you provide some code on what you tried?

Comment: code is some sensitive one I just keep it very simple to explain. I just want to know the configurations and steps required related to this task.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `ServletContextListener` to implement to execute or load static data during startup of the server and even you can destroy once server is stopped .

```
public class YourContextListner
       implements ServletContextListener{

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
//write the code to destroy the object 
}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
//write the code to load your JSON data as Key value 
}
}
```

and you have to make an entry in web.xml to do mapping of your contextListner

```
<listener>
<listener-class>
  com.yourpackageName.YourContextListner
</listener-class>
```

You can even use JSON parser API to parse those data and stored into Key value pair . Hope this helps Thanks